# Net amount not calculating for event registration

Tags: civievent, registration, reports

Civicrm 5.7.0/Wordpress 4.9.8:

When I manually enter an **event registration** that needs a payment processor fee, prior to civicrm upgrade to 5.7.0 from 4.7.19, there was an area at the bottom of the form called "Additional Details". In that section I could enter the processor fee amount and the net amount would be automatically calculated. In 5.7.0 that section is now gone. After I complete the registration I can go to the contact's profile and edit the corresponding Contribution where the Additional Details still exist although the net amount field beneath the fee is missing (Perhaps because of the changes listed at  https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/civicrm-56-release). When I enter the processor fee amount the net amount is not calculated in reports. Event registration reports will show registration fee, processor fee amount, and net amount but the net is not gross (reg fee) minus processor fee. It replicates the gross amount.

This does not happen when entering a contribution only, just when registering for an event. I have on rare occasions seen this happen on previous version when someone has used our online registration page but maybe only three or four times out of 100 registrants. I would then have to delete the transaction and rebuild it manually in order to get the processor fee to show up and calculate the net. Under the circumstances listed above that will no longer be possible.

Has anyone else experienced this and have a fix?
I have tried turning off custom fields and activated past events all with the same results. Also, NO event reports show the correct calculation as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!  Thanks for reporting that.  As you noted, in 5.6 the net amount is not displayed on those forms now since it was being automatically calculated anyway.  I have recreated your issue and it seems to be related to contributions generally rather than specifically related to events.  The net amount is being calculated correctly when the contribution is first created but edits to the fee amount are not causing re-calculation of the net amount.  I have created an issue here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/552

Comment: Thank you. The "Additional Details" is missing from the bottom of the Event Registration area unlike in v4.7.19 of civiCRM. Has it been removed from the 5.6 version? That is where I was able to enter processor fees at which point the net value was calculated correctly. In order to add the fee now, I have to go to the contribution tab of the attendee. If I add a fee to a contribution that is specifically related to an event, the net is incorrectly calculated (not subtracted at all). If I enter just a contribution with processor fee that is NOT related to an event, the calculation is correct.

Comment: Pulled from the issue page linked above: "eileen commented 3 days ago
Owner
@ayduns yes - we can close this - although there is a question as to whether we should attempt to fix any issues - bearing in mind that

it's a rare operation- ie a manual edit of amount on a site that cares about net_amount" . I use this operation fairly regularly during our registration process and we need to track fees so that we have an accurate net. Any chance this will get fixed? Or is there a patch/edit I can do? Thanks again.

Comment: There is a PR linked from the issue that has been merged and should be in 5.8 (due today) which should fix any new edits you make.  The question was about whether to recalculate the net_amount on existing contributions - that is not part of the fix.  So once you have updated to 5.8 you can go back to other ones you have edited and resave those to correct net_amount.

Comment: Thank you. We don't have the option right now to install a copy so it looks like I should wait for the final release. Any idea when that might happen? Thanks again.